# how to create a loading windows with faded background in windows application?

Tags: c#, loading, windows

I`m trying to create a loading windows with faded ( Blured ) background , that lock all the other windows

any issue for fade the background to lock other windows ?!

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
{
  if (item is Window 
      && item.Id != yourWindow )
  {
     item.Enabled = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With WPF I used something similar.

I created a usercontrol which has the app size with transparent background, and in the center, a loading faded form.

As the control is loaded top most, the control lock the app (user cannot click anywhere because of the transparent background). You can do some pretty graphical stuff with that.
Hope it helps.

Without WPF, you can use modal dialog.